# mysql_secure_installation password problem

Tags: mysql

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 with LAMP.
As the password for MySQL is the same like the root password of the server i want to change the password with mysql_secure_installation

I follow the steps put root password of server, then choose new password for MySQL, confirm password, all other questions with y then systemctl restart MySQL.

Then i want to login to MySQL with MySQL -u root -p and then i put the new password i changed but i get "access denied"
I installed 3 times the server new but every time the same result.

Does someone has an idea what is my fault?

Comment: Hi Tom, please explain in details what steps are you doing.

Answer (score 6):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239970/connect-to-mysql-server-without-sudo). You are forgetting to add "sudo" since you are using the root user to login into MySQL.

`sudo mysql -u root -p`

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 with MySQL Version 14.14 Distribution 5.7.25.

Comment: Help me understand the down vote. Is this not the solution?

Comment: that is absolutely the correct answer, thank you!  I came here for exactly the OP's situation and you saved me!

Comment: Nope, this is not the answer, because if you try it you'll see that with sudo, it doesn't matter what password you put

Comment: For root access, the password does not matter? Or there is still an access denied error when running with superuser privileges?

Comment: You don't even need to use `sudo` with a password. You *should* be able to login with `mysql -u root -p` while logged in as ANY non-`root` system user.